# Creating a java library

Tags: api, netbeans, jar, java

While I was working on a Java EE project I created some utility classes. I like to package them to a Jar and share it with the community. 
 I have all the classes in one separate package. I'm using Netbeans IDE.

1. What is the easiest  way to make that package a Jar lib?
   (Can NetBeans handle all it for me?)
2. What are the important points I should consider?
3. Where can I share it, then other who are interested can use it and help me improve it?
   (GitHub? Google Code? SourceForge? Or somewhere else? )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. NetBeans *can* do it, but IMO if you're releasing an open-source project, you should release it with a Maven, Ant, or similar build script.
2. Make it work? Have docs that don't suck? Have great tests and examples? Make sure it's not just another collection of utilities that already exist? Without knowing any details, it's difficult to know what exactly you want. I suspect this portion in particular is off-topic.
3. Make it available as a Maven artifact. Put the source in GitHub or somewhere else; who cares where the source lives as long as it'll be relatively long-lived and it's easily accessible?

Comment: Thanks!   1). `NetBeans can do it` , how?   2). `release it with a Maven, Ant, or similar build script.` Where should I begin?, not very much  familiar with them 3).  `great tests and examples` , `tests` yeah, a good point.

Comment: @agentmilindu No clue, don't use NetBeans. I'd assume there's a trivial packaging menu choice somewhere. Any Maven, Ant, or similar build project's tutorial(s).